# find + xargs + cat does not work with --name argument

Tags: find, cat, xargs

I'm trying to concatenate all the files of a  that ends with coref extension.

This works (but add unwanted files):

```
find ../corpus/dev/txt/ | xargs cat
```

This not works.

```
find ../corpus/dev/txt/ -name '*.coref' | xargs cat
```

In the second comand find returns 1566 results but xrags cat does nothing.

Why the -name arguments mess it all?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-print0` like this:

```
  find ../corpus/dev/txt/ -name '*.coref' -print0 | xargs -0 cat
```

if you find to many files and the xargs list gets too long, you can try this:

```
  find ../corpus/dev/txt/ -name '*.coref' -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 cat >> /tmp/file
```